# Alias a linked Server in SQL server management studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hoping someone can help - is there a way in SQL server management studio 2008 R2 that I can alias a linked SQL server?

I have a server, added by IP address, to which I do not have the login credentials - however as the connection is already setup I can login ok.

Issue is that, this is a dev environment, prior to a live deployment and the IP I have as a linked server needs to be 'accessible' by my stored procs under a different name, eg 'myserver' not 192.168.xxx.xxx...

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 26):

This method seems to work:

http://alexpinsker.blogspot.com/2007/08/how-to-give-alias-to-sql-linked-server.html

The details in case that link goes bad:

> There are no problems to add SQL linked server to the specific host
>   running it. But what if you need to give it an alias, rather than use
>   hostname as linked server name?   Here is how to do it:
>
> Step 1:
>
> - In SQL Server Management Studio open Linked Servers and then 'New Linked Server'.
> - Inside of appeared wizard – Select the General tab.
> - Specify alias name in "Linked server" field.
> - Select SQL Native Client as provider.
> - Add sql_server in "Product Name" field (that's the magic).
> - In "Data Source" – specify name of the host to be used as linked server.
>
> Step 2:
>
> - In Security tab – specify proper security options (e.g. security context)
>
> Step 3:
>
> - In Server Options tab – set "Data Access", RPC, "Rpc Out" and "Use    Remote Collation" to true.

Comment: What is the notation to select from a table on this server then?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps to create new alias->all programs->microsoft sql server 2008 R2->Configuration tools-> select sql server configuration manager->select alias->new alias->then enter server name

Comment: Thanks. That seems to allow aliasing of a server to connect to when doing so directly from SQL management studio (which will still be useful - thanks), but my main problem is updating a 'linked server' from one of my Dev VMs..

Comment: look into kerberos double hop problem when connecting to linked from remote machine